# Sudden start of agression

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, aggression

I have one female cat and one male. Both are neutered. About 4 months ago for no reason our male cat started "picking" on our female. He chases her out of the house, pushes her away from her food and generally stalks her and attacks her most of the time.

We have come home from work and there will be lumps of fur everywhere where he has been fighting with her. He is 2 and she is nearly 4. It has become very worrying to the point that sometimes our female will not come into the house if he is in as well. I even have to monitor feeding so that she gets some food.

Can anyone suggest how to solve this or what may be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like sexual aggression to me. By neutering you are only reducing masculine behavior of the male. It doesn't disappear. Also different males are different. Some super males retain even more masculinity after neutering.

And there are some submissive females. They are often coerced more easily.

One easy solution is available. Buy male pheromone from market and rub it often on the buttock of the female cat. The male will get super confused.

Comment: Do you have any resources to back up why you think it is _sexual_ aggression?

Comment: https://www.veterinarypracticenews.com/sexual-aggression-in-neutered-cats/